# DynamoDB: how to design a schema for an item with tags (descriptors)?

Tags: database-design, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I want to design a DynamoDB table for e.g. a blog site where each `post` could include zero to three "tags" (similar to the keywords/tags that a Stack Overflow can include prior to posting). The access pattern would be to get all `posts` with `tag1`, `tag2`, and/or `tag3`. If it makes a difference, the data interface layer is Graphql via Appsync via Amplify >_<)

1. Can Dynamo support this access pattern effectively? I keep reading that Dynamo is not great where the access pattern involves filtering; however, I'm not sure whether perhaps this access pattern can be implemented in Dynamo without relying upon filtering.
2. If Dynamo cannot effectively support this access pattern, are there some recommended alternatives? E.g., if Aurora is better solution for the `tags` specifically, what design pattern would combine `posts` in Dynamo with `tags` in Aurora?
3. What is an effective way to determine all tags? For example, `react-select` is a [neat tool](https://react-select.com/home) for building a tag-select component that requires the array of possible values. Is there a way to track such metadata?

Comment: you can WORKAROUND by having TAG#TagName as a GSI and blogid as sk of sgi. but it will become tricky if you will have more than 5 tags or you have to access data by some other attribute, since at most 5 GSIs are supported. You may look at other nosql implementations where your access patterns are supported

Comment: Actually, the 5 GSI limit is no longer a thing, though you shouldn’t start creating them without thinking it through because you still have to pay for all of the GSIs you create. https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/12/amazon-dynamodb-increases-the-number-of-global-secondary-indexes-and-projected-index-attributes-you-can-create-per-table/

Comment: I don’t know about how it works with your data access layer, but it sounds like you have a many-to-many relationship between tag and post, which DynamoDB recommends modeling as an adjacency list. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-adjacency-graphs.html